# Rigging Character - Parent and Child Bones FK Rig Malfunction

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, workflow

I’m new to rigging and this model is my first attempt.

But because of that, I’m of course having some minor issues ( that I hope remain minor lol ).

### The Problem

[image]

I’m following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uHY_GuKVSM&t=861s) concerning a spine rig. It seems as though I and a few others in the comments are having the same issue at the timestamped 13:25 mark.

When Dikko selects "DEF_spine.001" and "DEF_hips.001" to parent them with "CTRL_hips.001", his parent to child relationship is the only one rotating. The rest of the deformation bones stay put along with the “CTRL_COG” and “FK_torso” bones. This is the effect that’s supposed to be achieved.

However, when I rotate "CTRL_hips.001" after making it the parent to "DEF_hips.001" ( in my scenario as I only have one bone there ), all of my deformation bones rotate. This is not supposed to happen.

### What I’ve Attempted

I’ve done very simple rigs with FK and IK controls before with success and I’ve tried various things to fix this issue.

I was thinking that maybe because “DEF_hips.001” is attached to the entire deformation chain that it’s causing the entire thing to move when it’s made the child of “CTRL_hips.001”. But should “DEF_hips.001” not inherit the properties of “CTRL_hips.001” if it becomes the child of that instead of the “CTRL_hips.001” apparently inheriting the properties of “DEF_hips.001”?

I should note I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2f_JoUA0ec) to replicate the basic heat bone method to avoid initial errors I had. That's what the "dupe / duplication" collection is for.

### My Files

[Attached in my box are two files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HAzSUKIHn8aa89zJ91Sfz1bqJ-4rlmFV?usp=sharing) people can open to see what I’m doing wrong. One is called “base” ( original ) and “error” what’s replicating the problem above.

Also his a visual of what my current FK setup looks like in both files.

[image]

Comment: the files are private and not accessible.

Comment: @Blunder
Thanks for pointing out the error. I've made the files viewable. 

Please let me know if there are any other errors.

Comment: You're welcome. But the files are still private ;-)

Comment: @Blunder Oh my god I'm doing to die lmao.  Is this below link working now?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HAzSUKIHn8aa89zJ91Sfz1bqJ-4rlmFV?usp=sharing

Comment: Good news, everyone! I ( think ) figured this out on my own! 

Below was my solution. 

[1] I had to remove the “DEF_hips.001” bone as a child from the rest of the deformation rig. 

[2] Then I had to make it the parent of both the left and right def_hip bones so it controls everything from the hips downward.

[3] Then I had to make “DEF_hips.001” the child of “CTRL_hips.001”. 

So far it’s working, but in case this backfires, I am still open to feedback of other methods to achieve what Dikko’s tutorial is doing.

Answer (score 2):

I've not run into any errors onward and the control works as intended!

1. I had to remove the “DEF_hips.001” bone as a child from the rest of the deformation rig.
2. Then I had to make it the parent of both the left and right def_hip bones so it controls everything from the hips downward.
3. Then I had to make “DEF_hips.001” the child of “CTRL_hips.001”.